# Initialize int array with length of a input string in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I receive these errors
1. cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
2. expected constant expression
3. 'numbers' : unknown size

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str;
int input_num;
int sum;

cout << "Enter the number:" << endl;
getline(cin, str);
const int length = str.length();
cout << "Length:" << length<<endl;
//input_num = stoi(str);
int numbers[length];

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You cannot declare a stack allocated array who's size is not known at compile time (without a compiler extension)

Comment: Unfortunately, that duplicate doesn't mention that you should just use `std::vector` because it's explicitly disallowed in the title.

Comment: Just as a heads up for anybody else arriving here searching for the same thing I was 4 years later, the answer with the vector is EXACTLY what I needed and granted that this question had it's issues in the way it was asked, there's no reason it should keep getting downvoted. I appreciate the question and the answer. It's what I needed and props to SO for fulfilling it's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the use of an array by a `std::vector`, and initialize the elements to `0`.

```
std::vector<int> numbers(length, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array has to be a constant expression greater than 0.

You should use standard class `std::vector<int>` instead.

For example

```
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<int> numbers( length );
```

If the user has to enter a number of type for example `int` (that is the number might be in the range of acceptable values of object of type int) then you could define the array beforehand the following way

```
#include <limits>

//...

int numbers[std::limits<int>::digits10 + 1];
```